# Positioning a container next to its menu

Tags: beginner, html, css, layout

I'm a beginner in CSS and need help with a suggestion.

I'm working on a project, in which I managed to position `container_main` right next to `container_menu` giving the remaining dimension of the screen, giving it relative position and floating it to the right. `container_menu` has a dimension and a fixed position specified.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*Contenedor de la barra de navegacion: Columna*/
.container_menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 18rem;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
}

/*Barra de navelación: Elemento <ul>*/
.container_menu .menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.container_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container_menu .menu li a{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container_menu .menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.container_main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 66.31rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

p {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 20rem;
  border: .7rem solid white;;
  padding: 5rem;
  margin: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>MDN - Mockup</title>
</head>
<body class="wrapper">
  <nav class="container_menu">

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Teaching Activities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Literacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership Opportunities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Comunity</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main class="container_main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
      voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
      non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </main>

  <<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know if the characteristics I gave the containers are ideal, or if there is a better way to get the same result using other properties.

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble to realize what were your initial whishes, since the current choices lead to some inconveniences (as it already appears in the reduced "snippet box").

Here is what I can|can't understand:

- You want to keep menu always visible and located at the same place regardless how user scrolls.
  So **using `container_menu {position: fixed;}` is ok**.
- You want to have main container occuping the rightmost place, in front of `container_menu` and starting at the top of the window.
  So **using `container_main {float: right;}` is ok**.
- But why did you also set its postion to relative? Without adding some of `top|left|right|bottom` properties it changes nothing to its own location. In the other hand, it might be useful to constraint its `<p>` childs if they had for example `fixed` position but they don't.
  So **using `container_main {position: relative;}` is useless**.
- Since you set fixed `width` values for `container_main` and its `<p>` children, depending on the window width it may result in a (likely) unwanted layout: as soon as the window is small enough, `container_main` partially or totall overwrites `container_menu`.
  So **regarding *only* this point** (but see also below) **you should add `container_menu {z-index: 1;}`** (or any other
  convenient value, depending on other elements not currently showed).
- For the same reason, if the window width is smaller than the fixed `<p>` children, their content becomes cropped.
  So **you had better using a totally different technique**, such as setting `container_menu` postion to fixed, with a left margin equal to `container_menu`width, and using percentage for `container_main` width

Here is an example using the above technique:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/*Contenedor de la barra de navegacion: Columna*/
.container_menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 18rem;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
}

/*Barra de navelación: Elemento <ul>*/
.container_menu .menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.container_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container_menu .menu li a{
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container_menu .menu li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.container_main {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 18rem;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

p {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60%;
  border: .7rem solid white;;
  padding: 5rem;
  margin: 10rem auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>MDN - Mockup</title>
</head>
<body class="wrapper">
  <nav class="container_menu">

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Teaching Activities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Literacy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Leadership Opportunities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Comunity</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main class="container_main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
      voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
      non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
       ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
       non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

  </main>

  <<footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```